# What's the Pythonic Way to Build Elegant Dataclasses Dynamically (Or Not Dataclasses At All)?

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple, python-dataclasses

I'm building a library to read from input and build fairly high level libraries for serialization/unserialization. The inputs will be well structured, but could change and/or be customized, so pre-building all the class types is not possible. Example code follows:

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

# I'm including the yaml_string below as an example of the input.
yaml_string = """
data_store: 'foo'
storage_connection_type: 'bar'
connection:
    endpoint: 'qaz'
    access_key_id: 'qoo'
"""

top_node = make_dataclass('Top node', ['data_store', 'storage_connection_type', 'connection'])
nested_node = make_dataclass('Nested node', ['endpoint', 'access_key_id'])

n = nested_node('qaz', 'qoo')
t = top_node('foo', 'bar', n)

print(t.data_store) #=> foo
print(t.connection.endpoint) #=> qaz
```

The last steps are what I'm looking to deliver - using the dot notation, allowing a high level user to read/write to classes is extremely powerful.

Unfortunately, the code above is painful - it means I have to maintain a catalog of classes created - which, generally is fine, but when you start getting into nested objects, it feels ugly.

Am I overdoing it with data classes? is there a better way? I've looked at `__slots__` and `namedtuples`, and both seem to have similar issues.

Comment: Have you considered just dictionaries? Or JSON? There's also a yaml module in stdlib if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I use a dict, I don't get the syntactic elegance of the dot notation.

Comment: Then use `__dict__` via `setattr`

Comment: you might want to look into full-fledged serialization library like marshmallow. e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231334/define-fields-programmatically-in-marshmallow-schema) explains how to build marshmallow schemas dynamically in a similar way to dataclasses, but more powerful.

Comment: I hadn't investigated marshmallow that much, but now, based on the need, I've decided to swap over. Not sure if I should still leave this open - if someone wants to propose an answer, I'll accept it, but not going to use the solution.