# Apply attribute to all fields by default in marshmallow, python

Tags: python, marshmallow

Is it possible to add an attribute by default to a Marshmallow schema?

For instance, I would like to create a deserialisation only schema. That would imply adding `load_only` to every field. Find an example below:

```py
class Fruits(Schema)
    apple = fields.Str(load_only=True)
    banana = fields.Str(load_only=True)
    pineapple = fields.Str(load_only=True)
    pear = fields.Str(load_only=True)
    ...
```

Is there a more elegant way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a partial function binding the load_only attribute:

```py
from functools import partial 

deserializer = partial(fields.Str, load_only=True)

class Fruits(Schema):
    apple = deserializer()
    ...
```

Or, you could leverage `vars()` and set the attribute directly

```py
class Fruits(Schema):
    for attr in ('apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'pear'):
        vars()[attr] = fields.Str(load_only=True)
```

### Edit:

Going off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42231334/7867968), you might be able to do something similar:

```py
def create_fields(field_pairs):
    for field, type_ in field_pairs:
        yield field, getattr(
            marshmallow.fields, 
            type_
        )(load_only=True) # set load_only=True here


fields = dict(create_fields((
    ('banana', 'String'), 
    ('apple', 'Integer'), 
    ...
)))


Fruits = type('Fruits', (marshmallow.Schema,), fields)
```

Comment: Bending the rules a little bit there. The first approach is actually ok but that works for ```String``` only . You have to define a partial for each other data type you plan to use. I guess my example could have been more complete and include other data types.

Comment: @renatodamas I've added an edit that might get you a little closer. Doing an attribute lookup returns the function and you can apply the appropriate kwarg to the field. Then use the `type` function to build the class dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with the following:

```py
class Fruits(Schema)
    apple = fields.Str()
    banana = fields.Str()
    pineapple = fields.Str()
    pear = fields.Str()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for field in self.declared_fields.values():
            field.load_only = True
```

Now one could simply isolate that "ugly" attribute setter:

```py
class DeserializerSchema(Schema):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for field in self.declared_fields.values():
            field.load_only = True

class Fruits(DeserializerSchema)
    ...
```

An alternative way would even use the `Meta` class (documentation [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.SchemaOpts)):

```py
class Fruits(Schema)
    apple = fields.Str()
    banana = fields.Str()
    pineapple = fields.Str()
    pear = fields.Str()

    class Meta:
       load_only = ("apple", "banana", "pineapple", "pear")
```

I personally don't like much this option since it requires statically adding each field to the list/tuple in the `Meta` class.